# how to insert href of <a> tag inside a variable and download by curl?

Tags: php, curl, hyperlink, download

i am trying to save pages as html document to my host and open it by PHP & download some links ( e.g http://test.com/.1.mp3 & http://test.com/2.apk ) 
to my own host .
everything is good except the section i want put **href** attributes of  tags in a variable .

i use a function that download link by curl  . when i insert download link directly it works fine , but in my code the href goes in a variable without " "
and curl download a 0kb file .

here u can see the code and my explantion .

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 include ("simple_html_dom.php"); // sourceforge html dom

 $host= " ";  // no need
 $target = "http://example.com/?p=17977";  // target page


 // to save page as html

function gethtm($urlm) {
$url  = $urlm;
$time = time() + rand();
$patha = 'html/temp-html.html';

$fp = fopen($patha, 'w');

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

fclose($fp);
  }

// download the link

 function downloadurl ($urlf) {

    $url  = $urlf;
$path = 'file/temp.apk';


$ch = curl_init($url);
if($ch === false)
{
        die('Failed to create curl handle');
}

$fp = fopen($path, 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

}
// save trget
 gethtm($target);

// find download link   
$html = file_get_html('html/temp-html.html');
foreach($html->find('a') as $element ) {

    if( strpos($element->href , 'http://dl2.packdl') !== false) {

        $linka = $element->href;
      }
   }
echo $linka;

/*   here is where u can see my problem if i insert download link myself it
    download it and works
   but does not work by  $linka !
   i tried this values ---->   $linka   '"'.$linka.'"'     "'".$linka."'"   '.$linka.'
also tried this values inside of function but everytime it return 0kb file
but if i insert download link :  "http://example.com/file.rar"   
it works and download file ...  
 that's my question how to download link inside $linka ?

*/
 downloadurl('"'.$linka.'"');

 ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

that's my question how to download link inside $linka ?

Comment: What function is `gf()` meant to be? And pretty certain you do _not_ need any quotes around that string at all, unless that function `gf()` has a _very_ unusual implementation.

Comment: gf() download  link source using curl .

Comment: Then please post the implementation of that function, we cannot guess it.

Comment: yea sorry just did it

Comment: You call `curl_init()` twice, why?

Comment: And given that code you certainly should _not_ put quote chars around that URL string just as I said before.

Comment: You mean in second function ? yea i just noticed . i copy pasted many codes to fix this , i guess i forgot to remove it

Comment: ayy yes i just removed second function and used code directly , also removed quote and now it works like a boss